# global scope createReadStream doesn't work for callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, fs

```
const http = require("http");
const { createReadStream } = require("fs");
const stream = createReadStream("./big.txt", "utf-8");

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  console.log("hehehe");
//   const stream = createReadStream("./big.txt", "utf-8");
  stream.on("open", () => {
    console.log("hohoho");
    stream.pipe(res);
  });
});

server.listen(5000);
```

[code result]

```
hehehe
```

1. if `const stream = createReadStream("./big.txt", "utf-8");` is outside callback
   then the server connection does'nt work properly.
2. if I put `const stream = createReadStream("./big.txt", "utf-8");` inside callback then everything works.
3. it seems like `stream.pipe(res)` does what `res.end()` does.
   but i don't understand How `pipe(res)` can do that job.

Answer (score 0):

Well I just got into this problem as well, and my guess is because the file for read stream had already been opened before the server is created. So the `stream.on("open")`'s callback function will never be called.

Comment: Your guess is correct :)